# Eliminar propiedad de objeto si es null dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, matrices

Buenos dias tengo un problema.
estoy consumiendo una api  que ejecuta consultas dinamicas la cual me trae más de 20 campos, a veces ocupa 5,8,20 depende de la consulta y el resto de los campos me los trae como null.

[image: ejemplo pequeño, la consulta me trae el id como null]

quisiera saber como puedo hacer para eliminar dinámicamente las propiedades de los objetos que sean null ya que al ser mas de 20 campos necesito que se eliminen dinamicamente por que cada consulta es diferente.

servicio que trae mis datos:

```
    /Aquí tengo otra duda que sería mejor para hacer este proceso, setear los valores del API.
    //en una matriz de tipo File, file: File[] = []
    //o en un Objeto Tipo File, fileobjeto: File;

    //variables
        file: File[] = [];
        fileobjecto: File;
    //servicio
         getDatos(idSist: number, idProc: number, pidm) {
            this.restService.get("files/" + idSist + "/" + idProc + '/' + pidm).subscribe((data) => {
              this.file = data;
                console.log("datos: ", this.file);
            });

  }
```

Clase tipo File:

```
export class File {
    id: number;
    uztfile_STRING1: string;
    UZTFILE_STRING2: string;
    UZTFILE_STRING3: string;
    UZTFILE_STRING4: string;
    UZTFILE_STRING5: string;
    UZTFILE_STRING6: string;
    UZTFILE_STRING7: string;
    UZTFILE_STRING8: string;
    UZTFILE_STRING9: string;
    UZTFILE_STRING10: string;
    UZTFILE_NUMBER2: number;

constructor(id: number, uztfile_STRING1: string, UZTFILE_STRING2: string, UZTFILE_STRING3: string, UZTFILE_STRING4: string, UZTFILE_STRING5: string,
        UZTFILE_STRING6: string, UZTFILE_STRING7: string, UZTFILE_STRING8: string, UZTFILE_STRING9: string, UZTFILE_STRING10: string, UZTFILE_NUMBER2: number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.uztfile_STRING1 = uztfile_STRING1;
        this.UZTFILE_STRING2 = UZTFILE_STRING2;
        this.UZTFILE_STRING3 = UZTFILE_STRING3;
        this.UZTFILE_STRING4 = UZTFILE_STRING4;
        this.UZTFILE_STRING5 = UZTFILE_STRING5;
        this.UZTFILE_STRING6 = UZTFILE_STRING6;
        this.UZTFILE_STRING7 = UZTFILE_STRING7;
        this.UZTFILE_STRING8 = UZTFILE_STRING8;
        this.UZTFILE_STRING9 = UZTFILE_STRING9;
        this.UZTFILE_STRING10 = UZTFILE_STRING10;
        this.UZTFILE_NUMBER2 = UZTFILE_NUMBER2;
    }
```

Comment: Lo mas recomendable es que redisenes tu servicio, y el tipo de respuesta.

Comment: Ufffffffffffffffff se me ocurre que recorras cada elemento del array, y vayas preguntando si una propiedad es null, si es null ir eliminando con el delete que tienen los objetos para eliminar propiedades.

Comment: que tal si haces algo como `this.UZTFILE_STRING8 = UZTFILE_STRING8 || null`;, de hecho puede hacerse de otra forma porque UZTFILE_STRTING no es un Array?? y la posicion muestra el valor del string asi puedes usar el filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no veo el porque quieres eliminar los valores null. Aunque la solución mas fácil creo que seria la siguiente:

hago un `item[key]=== null` y no un `!item[key]` por el simple hecho de que si te viene un 0 o un false o algún parámetro que quizás te interesa se eliminaría.

```
 getDatos(idSist: number, idProc: number, pidm) {
            this.restService.get("files/" + idSist + "/" + idProc + '/' + 
            pidm).subscribe((data) => {
              this.file = data.map(item => {
                 Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
                    if (item[key] === null) delete item[key];
                 });
                 return item;
              });
                console.log("datos: ", this.file);
            });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funcionó, necesitaba borrar las propiedades nulas xq estába exportando un archivo XLS y se exportaba con las columnas nulas